# Function returning undefined variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript, when i call this function from another js file i get undefined in my console output. Can I return the json object know as "obj" and not have it be undefined?

```
module.exports = {
  getTechnicPackInfo: function(id){
    var http = require("https");

    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "hostname": "solder.io",
      "path": "/api/aurora-crafters/modpacks/" + id,
      "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/Json",
        "authorization": "Bearer 00000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];
      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        var obj = JSON.parse(body);    
        return obj; 
      });
    });

    req.end();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning a function call? Shouldn't you just be returning `obj`?

Comment: apologies forgot to remove that, it was there in error when i was pasting here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You didn't return anything

The issue you're having is caused by not returning any value at all from the function `getTechnicPackInfo`, not the inner functions.

What you want to do is use the `fetch` api to fetch all of the stuff you are trying to get and return the value returned by `fetch`. This allows you to do the following:

```
getTechnicPackInfo(...).then(resultingData => resultingData.json()).then(parsedData => ...)
```

This works because `fetch` returns a `Promise` allowing you to then parse the data with `.json` (it has it's own function because you can't simply do `JSON.parse`) which returns another `Promise`

---

### `fetch` doesn't exist in Node by default

`fetch` is not a default function built into node.js, therefore, you have to import it after installing [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

#### Command Line:

```
npm install --save node-fetch
```

#### Node.js:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Comment: Okay, I will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from the getTechnicPackInfo function.

What you can do is to use util.promisify your http request and then return the promise.

Answer (score 0):

the answer from above is correct but the api fetch is not present in node env, there is a module npm to add it: "[node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)".

if you do not want to install this module a solution would be to add a callback argument to the function getTechnicPackInfo() :

*file1.js:*

```
module.exports = {
    getTechnicPackInfo: function(id, callback){
        var http = require("https");
        var options = {
            "method": "GET",
            "hostname": "solder.io",
            "path": "/api/aurora-crafters/modpacks/" + id,
            "headers": {
                "accept": "application/json",
                "content-type": "application/Json",
                "authorization": "Bearer 00000000000000000000000000000"
            }
        };
        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            var chunks = [];

            res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on("end", function () {
                var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                var obj = JSON.parse(body);    
                callback(obj); 
            });
        });
        req.end();
    }
}
```

*file2.js*

```
var f = require('./file1.js');
f.getTechnicPackInfo(123456, function(obj) {
    //do what you need with obj
})
```